# Removing/deallocating pushed stack from tabbar

Tags: swift

I have a tabbarcontroller with 4 "items" connected as root segues.
I also have a stack (Navcontroller with various VCs) that is pushed from the tabbarcontroller, ie the bottom one on the picture.  The stack takes the user down a path, and at the end I want to dismiss/deallocate this entire stack and return to the tabbar.  How should I remove/dismiss/deallocate this stack/path ? should I just create a segue from the last VC to like tabbar item 1 or is there a better way to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `viewControllers` property on `UINavigationController` to do arbitrary bulk sets of the the navigation stack

so to get back to the top...

```
if let navigationController = myCurrentViewController.navigationController, top = navigationController.viewControllers.first {
    nav.setViewControllers([top], animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please comment what variables vc and nav is. vc is self?

Comment: see edit `myCurrentViewController` would be self if invoked from current view controller

Comment: Sorry dont understand how this is helping me to get back to the tabbarcontroller

Comment: can you explain how you transition from the tabVC to the navVC . Do you perhaps 'present' it rather than 'pushing' it as you describe ?